# R : Renderui not initializing properly

Tags: r, shiny

I have made a shiny UI.
Most of the time it's initializing correctly but sometimes when I load my app the combobox created by renderui isn't displayed and I have to re-load my url.

Here a picture when the problem occurs :
[image]
Here a picture when it's working :
[image]
Here my code :

***Ui part :***

```
rm(list = ls(all = TRUE)) 

library(shiny)
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)
library(plotly)
# On definit le path
setwd("Mypath")

#UI Shiny app
shinyUI(

tabsetPanel(id='tabs',


          tabPanel("Report",
                   shinyjs::useShinyjs(),


                   #hr() ligne
                   hr(),
                   # Multiple choices Listbox pour Group
                   h4(uiOutput("Area")),

                   column(4,actionButton("Act",h4("Launch the report",style = "color:blue"),icon = icon("refresh"), class="btn-primary", style="color:white")

                   )

          )

) # END TabsetPanel

)   # End ShinyServer UI
```

Server Part :

```
# 0 : We load the libraries
library(shinyjs)
#Repository
setwd("MyPath")


shinyServer (function(input, output, session){
shinyjs::disable("Act")

withProgress(message = 'Loading data', value = 0, {

# Increment the progress bar, and update the detail text.
incProgress(1/2, detail = paste(" ... please WAIT"))


merge_file <- structure(list(Workareabis = c("G3", "G1", "G3", "G2", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G4", "G4", "G4", "G4", "G4", 
                               "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G5", "G5", 
                               "G5", "G5", "G3", "G3", "G5", "G3", "G3", "G5", "G3", "G3", "G5", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G5", "G3", "G3", "G5", "G3", "G3", "G5", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G5", "G3", "G3", "G5", "G3", "G3", "G5", "G3", "G3", "G5", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G5", "G3", "G3", "G5", "G3", "G3", "G5", "G3", "G3", "G5", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G5", "G3", "G3", "G5", "G3", "G3", "G5", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G5", "G5", "G3", "G3", "G5", "G3", "G3", "G5", "G3", "G3", "G5", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G5", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G6", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G6", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G6", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G6", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G6", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G7", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G7", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G7", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G7", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", 
                               "G2", "G2", "G2", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G7", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G7", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G7", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G7", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G7", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G7", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G7", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G7", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G7", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G7", "G2", "G2", 
                               "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G2", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G7", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G7", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G7", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G6", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G7", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G7", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G7", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G7", "G3", "G2", "G2", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G7", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G7", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G6", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G6", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G6", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G6", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G6", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G6", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G6", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G6", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G6", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G6", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G6", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G7", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G7", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G7", 
                               "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G1", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G8", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G8", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G8", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G1", 
                               "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", 
                               "G3", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", 
                               "G3", "G9", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G9", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G9", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G2", "G2", "G10", "G10", "G10", "G10", "G10", "G10", 
                               "G10", "G10", "G3", "G10", "G10", "G10", "G10", "G10", "G10", 
                               "G10", "G10", "G10", "G10", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", 
                               "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", 
                               "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", 
                               "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G9", "G3", "G2", "G2", 
                               "G2", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G11", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G11", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G11", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G11", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G11", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G11", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G11", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G11", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G11", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G11", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G11", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G11", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G11", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G11", "G3", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G11", "G3", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G11", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G11", 
                               "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G11", 
                               "G3"), score = c(0, 0, 0, 8.21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.61, 0, 3.77, 
                                                0, 10.61, 17.83, 0, 0.68, 0, 15.03, 0.19, 0, 2.69, 0.58, 1.17, 
                                                0, 0, 0, 0, 1.08, 0, 0, 11.51, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                1.55, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.95, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22.63, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.83, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                0.28, 0, 2.6, 10.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.33, 
                                                0.84, 0.59, 0.82, 0, 0.2, 0, 3.19, 10.11, 0, 0, 1.97, 0.99, 0, 
                                                0, 0, 0, 21.83, 0, 0, 21.83, 4.82, 3.92, 24, 14.41, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8.32, 0, 4.16, 0, 0.87, 0, 
                                                0, 0.29, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.52, 24, 0, 0, 8.35, 
                                                0, 9.12, 3.08, 0, 4.07, 0, 0, 18.38, 16.29, 11.56, 0, 20.43, 
                                                0.54, 15.99, 12.32, 0, 0, 16.08, 0, 5.36, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                24, 0, 0, 0, 1.45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.19, 4.78, 0, 24, 0, 0, 6, 0, 
                                                0.35, 0.53, 0, 24, 7.85, 5.82, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.02, 0.08, 0, 0, 3.57, 0, 0.89, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.65, 0, 0, 0, 0.49, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.42, 0, 0, 1.42, 4.43, 0, 4.02, 
                                                9.56, 6.24, 1.49, 19.81, 0, 5.64, 8.98, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.07, 
                                                1.81, 6.12, 0.48, 3.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.09, 0, 0, 0, 1.09, 0, 
                                                7.94, 0, 3.32, 3.75, 24, 4.14, 0, 0, 0.11, 4.18, 0, 3.23, 19.52, 
                                                24, 0, 11.69, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.81, 1.2, 0.1, 0, 
                                                13.73, 0, 0, 3.51, 0, 9.59, 1.28, 0, 0, 2.72, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0.29, 14.1, 0, 3.79, 0.74, 0.02, 
                                                0, 5.05, 2.43, 0.36, 23.73, 0, 0, 8.15, 10.26, 7.66, 7.41, 7.5, 
                                                12.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8.98, 8.26, 0.08, 0, 0, 16.1, 
                                                1.18, 4.38, 0, 0, 10.86, 0, 0, 2.71, 0.03, 0, 0, 2.92, 0, 0.76, 
                                                0.02, 14.59, 0, 0.3, 0.18, 3.78, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.34, 0, 0.2, 
                                                0, 0, 1.39, 0.28, 0, 17.32, 0, 0, 4.54, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.03, 
                                                0, 0, 1.77, 0, 0, 0.44, 1.06, 3.13, 0, 0, 0.89, 2.07, 0, 0.13, 
                                                0, 0, 0, 0.03, 0, 0, 2.41, 3.28, 3.32, 2.25, 1.14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                1.14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.21, 0.3, 0.88, 0, 0, 0.93, 0, 1.11, 0, 0, 
                                                5.2, 1.41, 0.08, 1.67, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
                                                24, 0, 0, 0, 1.93, 2.54, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.68, 0.87, 0.87, 0, 
                                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.43, 0, 0.11, 0, 10.46, 0, 0, 0, 2.62, 
                                                0.07, 0, 0, 0, 3.77, 1.01, 0.02, 0, 0, 14.13, 0.42, 3.66, 0, 
                                                0.75, 0, 0, 0, 0.19, 0, 0, 11.09, 0, 0.57, 4.26, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                0, 0, 0, 2.33, 0, 0, 0, 0.78, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19.11, 0, 
                                                0.35, 0, 6.48, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.2, 0, 0, 
                                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0.38, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.61, 17.75, 
                                                24, 11.5, 24, 0, 0, 13.81, 1.43, 17.45, 5.02, 0, 0.46, 0, 0.41, 
                                                0, 19.07, 0.27, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.85, 0, 1.63, 0, 0, 5.73, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                0, 0, 3.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.67, 0.55, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7.51, 
                                                0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 8.36, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 3.52, 
                                                0, 0, 0, 0, 18.49, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.77, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.37, 1.75, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.07, 0, 6.69, 0, 
                                                2.7, 0, 0, 12.02, 0, 0, 12.02, 0, 0, 13.22, 0.07, 15.37, 15.4, 
                                                0, 13.12, 0, 0, 13.96, 0, 2.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.73, 0, 
                                                0, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.03, 0, 1.32, 0, 1.08, 1.02, 0, 
                                                0, 0, 1.67, 0.32, 0, 0, 14.48, 0, 24, 16.73, 0, 0, 0, 16.52, 
                                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                0, 0, 0, 0, 8.92, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8.92, 0, 0, 3.4, 0, 0.55, 
                                                0.01, 0, 0, 0, 3.49, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.69, 14.98, 9.09, 13.36, 0, 
                                                0, 0, 7.54, 4.1, 0, 16.38, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16.39, 0, 0.11, 
                                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                0, 0, 0, 0, 2.82, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.73, 1.58), Type = c("6", "6", 
                                                                                                    "6", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
                                                                                                    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
                                                                                                    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
                                                                                                    "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
                                                                                                    "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
                                                                                                    "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
                                                                                                    "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
                                                                                                    "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
                                                                                                    "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", 
                                                                                                    "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
                                                                                                    "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
                                                                                                    "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
                                                                                                    "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
                                                                                                    "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
                                                                                                    "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
                                                                                                    "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
                                                                                                    "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
                                                                                                    "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
                                                                                                    "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
                                                                                                    "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
                                                                                                    "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
                                                                                                    "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
                                                                                                    "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
                                                                                                    "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
                                                                                                    "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
                                                                                                    "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
                                                                                                    "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
                                                                                                    "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
                                                                                                    "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
                                                                                                    "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
                                                                                                    "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
                                                                                                    "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
                                                                                                    "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
                                                                                                    "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
                                                                                                    "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
                                                                                                    "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
                                                                                                    "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
                                                                                                    "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
                                                                                                    "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
                                                                                                    "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
                                                                                                    "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
                                                                                                    "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
                                                                                                    "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
                                                                                                    "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
                                                                                                    "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
                                                                                                    "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
                                                                                                    "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "F", "F", "F", 
                                                                                                    "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
                                                                                                    "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
                                                                                                    "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "H", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
                                                                                                    "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
                                                                                                    "I", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
                                                                                                    "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
                                                                                                    "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "M", "M", 
                                                                                                    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
                                                                                                    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
                                                                                                    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
                                                                                                    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
                                                                                                    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
                                                                                                    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
                                                                                                    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
                                                                                                    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
                                                                                                    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
                                                                                                    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
                                                                                                    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
                                                                                                    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
                                                                                                    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
                                                                                                    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
                                                                                                    "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
                                                                                                    "M")), .Names = c("Workareabis", "score", "Type"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                     900L), class = "data.frame")

colnames(merge_file) <- c("Workareabis","score","Type")



# Choice vector
vector_areasbis <- unique(merge_file$Workareabis)

# We display the combobox

output$Area <- renderUI({ 
  selectInput("Area",
              h4("Choose Group(s) :",style = "color:blue"), 
              c("All",as.character((vector_areasbis))), multiple=TRUE,selected = "All")
}) # End of renderUI 


incProgress(1, detail = paste("Data available"))        

shinyjs::enable("Act")

}) # End of WithProgress bar definition + data extraction


# Linked event
observeEvent(input$Act,{

shinyjs::disable("Act")
shinyjs::enable("Act")

}) # END

# End shiny server
})
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you provide sample code to re-create the problem please

Comment: I have updated the post with my codes + my data (through merge_file <- structure(list(Workareabis = ........). I think my code is alright but it's a problem of loading concerning renderUI : 8/10 it's OK but sometimes i have to refresh the URL because the combobox isn't displayed.